# How to add label/badge on bookable product based on their booking status

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, labels

How to display a badge/label on the product image based on the booking status of the product.

Ex: If the product is booked for 1 month it shows the product status as "Booked"
and after 1 month completion of booking duration automatically it changes the product status to "Available for Booking"

Comment: You've probably got two choices: either dynamically generate the product status on request - which I guess will be stored in post meta, so some sort of post meta fetch hook? - or set up a scheduled job to look through all of the products at the end of the day and update their booked status.

Comment: But this all sounds wrong to me anyway: don't you need to support future bookings? So if product A is booked until the end of the week won't your customers want to make a booking for next week in advance rather than having to come back on Monday to grab the product there and then?